# fwrite pipe to email in c code

Tags: c, popen, fwrite

I am trying to use popen to open a pipe to mail process and write a memory mapped array(shared_array) to the body of the email. The email sends but only lists the first entry of shared_array. Any help is appreciated

```
FILE *fp;
char (*shared_array)[MAXLINE]
shared_array= mmap(0,100*MAXLINE,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON,-1,0);  


fp = popen("mail -s testing joe@smith.com","w");
for(k =0; k<total_count;k++){
    fwrite(shared_array[k],sizeof(shared_array[k]),1,fp);
}
    fwrite(".\n",sizeof(char*),3,fp);
    pclose(fp);

    printf("\n\nEmail Sent\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Show us the declaration of `shared_array`, `sizeof` may not be what you need.

Comment: If there's less than `MALINE` number of "real" characters stored in `shared_array[k]` (or in any cell of `shared_array`), you're going to write a bunch of trailing binary garbage, which may well cause the `mail` command to stop reading.  Does your shared memory setup give you any way of knowing how long each entry/line of `shared_array` is?

Comment: `fwrite(".\n",sizeof(char*),3,fp);` is wrong, you are overflowing the string literal like crazy. It should be `sizeof(char)` or just 1, because `char` is defined to have size 1, so: `fwrite(".\n",1,3,fp);`.  And in the `fwrite` above, you probably want to do `strlen(shared_array[k])` and not dumping all the buffer, which after the \0-termination may contain garbage.

Comment: If your data is strings rather than binary, why are you even using `fwrite`?  Just use `fputs` or `fprintf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pablo had it right. I needed to use strlen

```
fwrite(shared_array[k],strlen(shared_array[k]),1,fp);
```

Comment: You should just use `fputs(shared_array[k], fp)` rather than mucking about with `fwrite` and sizes.